# align image and text content type - article

Tags: drupal

I am learning drupal. This is my first post in drupal.

I am trying to publish an article, so in editor I first copied the texts and then insert image. Then I have also uploaded the image. The problem is with alignment, my texts are not justified. And the image which is below the text is appearing at left of the text when the article is published. I tried align the image Right but still it is not working.

I want my texts to be justified and the image to appear at the right of the text, how can I do so?
Please see the attached image.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It wold be nice to know what theme you are using, if you created a sub-theme, etc.
But, if you are willing to use *inline styles* (I think it might be a bad idea) change the “Text format” from “Basic HTML” to “Full HTML”, edit the “source” and apply the necessary *inline styles*.